# mongodb: how to upgrade db?

Tags: mongodb

Hey I have mongodb which I have used for a long time. It's version is 1.2.2.
Now I have new server running centos 5.5. I know how to install mongodb on it.
It's version is 1.6.5.
I want to know how I can migrate my db files in /var/lib/mongo/ to 1.6.5?
It's just dbs and collections, no index files at all.
Is there any tools can easily do that for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copy over the original database files to the new server and restart mongod on the new system.
It might be necessary to to start mongod with the --upgrade  option in order to migrate existing database files to a new database format (has not changed since 1.4 but possibly between 1.2 and 1.6).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade to the just released 1.8.0-rc0 detailed instructions are at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Upgrading+to+1.8.0